# glm to dataset in caret R

Tags: r, caret

I could really use your help. I am trying to write an R script that takes some data and performs `glm` using the `caret` package. Here is my code:

```
set.seed(4000)
# Create training and test data with 80%-20% ratio
new_values$gender <- as.factor(new_values$gender)
trainingRows= createDataPartition(new_values$gender, p= .8, list= FALSE, times= 1)
training_data_set= new_values[trainingRows,]
test_data_set= new_values[-trainingRows,]
# Test training with 10 times cross-validation
fitness_control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10, savePredictions = TRUE)
# Train model with linear regression method (it takes about 5-10 minutes waiting time)
linear_regression <-train(gender~ ., data=training_data_set,method="glm",family=binomial(), trControl=fitness_control)
linear_regression
```

Here is the data table:
[new_data table](https://mega.nz/file/XIMDWYTY#0DC6o2S9Vf9jxYT0-VQdRwlHyT8RAsl11s1LryYk2hg)

When I try to run this script R takes really long time to load and after that I get this error message:

Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:

```
    Accuracy       Kappa    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :1     NA's   :1    
Error: Stopping
In addition: There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

The warnings are:

> Warning messages: 1: model fit failed for Fold01: parameter=none Error
> : protect(): protection stack overflow
>
> 2: model fit failed for Fold02: parameter=none Error : protect():
> protection stack overflow
>
> 3: model fit failed for Fold03: parameter=none Error : protect():
> protection stack overflow
>
> 4: model fit failed for Fold04: parameter=none Error : protect():
> protection stack overflow
>
> 5: model fit failed for Fold05: parameter=none Error : protect():
> protection stack overflow
>
> 6: model fit failed for Fold06: parameter=none Error : protect():
> protection stack overflow
>
> 7: model fit failed for Fold07: parameter=none Error : protect():
> protection stack overflow
>
> 8: model fit failed for Fold08: parameter=none Error : protect():
> protection stack overflow
>
> 9: model fit failed for Fold09: parameter=none Error : protect():
> protection stack overflow
>
> 10: model fit failed for Fold10: parameter=none Error : protect():
> protection stack overflow
>
> 11: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info =
> trainInfo,  ... :   There were missing values in resampled performance
> measures.

Comment: Is the data attached the entire dataset (ie you only have 32 rows)? And what does `warnings()` show?

Comment: @lhs yes its is the entire dataset. i added the warnings to the original post

Comment: I don't think `train()` with `method = 'glm'` does regularization, right? In which case you have way too many covariates for the number of observations. You may also have meant to exclude the first column of the data you provide from the predictors.